# How to set azure jars for pyspark to be able to read Blob Storage from jupyter?

Tags: azure, pyspark, jupyter

I am building an application for studying purposes. In this application, I have two docker containers mouted:

- azurite (which emulates a Azure Storage container) - mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite
- a jupyter notebook with pyspark - jupyter/pyspark-notebook

They are already in the same network and the comunication between them is not a problem.

My main problem is that I am trying to make pyspark to read files from Azure Storage with `spark.read.json(...)` but I can't beacause I`m not getting how to config pyspark jar files.

Below, my try:

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName('test') \
    .config(
        'spark.driver.extraClassPath', 
        '/home/jovyan/work/normalization/.jars/hadoop-azure-3.3.2.jar, /home/jovyan/work/normalization/.jars/azure-storage-8.6.6.jar') \
    .config(
        'fs.azure',
        'org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem') \
    .config(
        'fs.azure.account.key.devstoreaccount1.blob.core.windows.net',
        'Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw=='
    ) \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.json('wasbs://container@devstoreaccount1.blob.core.windows.net/path/to/file.json')
```

When I try to read the file, I get the following error:

```sh
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df = spark.read.json('wasbs://bronze@devstoreaccount1.blob.core.windows.net/pokemon_tcg/cards/2022/05/01/*.json')

File /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py:229, in DataFrameReader.json(self, path, schema, primitivesAsString, prefersDecimal, allowComments, allowUnquotedFieldNames, allowSingleQuotes, allowNumericLeadingZero, allowBackslashEscapingAnyCharacter, mode, columnNameOfCorruptRecord, dateFormat, timestampFormat, multiLine, allowUnquotedControlChars, lineSep, samplingRatio, dropFieldIfAllNull, encoding, locale, pathGlobFilter, recursiveFileLookup, allowNonNumericNumbers, modifiedBefore, modifiedAfter)
    227     path = [path]
    228 if type(path) == list:
--> 229     return self._df(self._jreader.json(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
    230 elif isinstance(path, RDD):
    231     def func(iterator):

File /usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py:1321, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1315 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1316     self.command_header +\
   1317     args_command +\
   1318     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1320 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321 return_value = get_return_value(
   1322     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1324 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1325     temp_arg._detach()

File /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py:111, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    109 def deco(*a, **kw):
    110     try:
--> 111         return f(*a, **kw)
    112     except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    113         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File /usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o40.json.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem$Secure not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2667)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3431)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3466)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1(DataSource.scala:747)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:745)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:577)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:274)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:245)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:405)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem$Secure not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2571)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2665)
    ... 29 more
```

What am I doing wrong???